# validate utf8 characters based on language , php

Tags: php, zend-framework, unicode, utf-8

I want to validate utf8 characters on the basis of the language that was selected previously. Any way of doing it??? Means, if i am selecting hindi , then i want to restrict users from entering other languages (like spanish , chinese etc.)

Comment: didn't understood your question, why you want to restrict?

Comment: The admin of the group previously selecting a language.But now the users can comment in any language. Is there any way to restrict users  while entering any other languages in comment fields available in the group.Any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the characters are all from certain Unicode blocks. I don't know Hindi but by the wikipedia page it's usually written in the [Devanagari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) alphabet, so this might work for this particular case:

```
// permit devanagari, white space, and numbers 
if (preg_match('/^[\p{Devanagari}\p{Z}\p{N}]+$/u', $text) {
    echo 'all well';
} else {
    echo 'illegal characters';
}
```

You can look up the list of blocks you can use in the [PCRE documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). This approach won't stop someone from posting English in a Turkish forum though, as the languages are written with characters from the same block.